# Authentication loop in django-rest-framework when accessing request.user

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-1.7

I've defined a custom authentication scheme in django-rest-framework 3.0.3 like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AnonymousUser
from rest_framework import authentication


class CustomAuthentication(authentication.BaseAuthentication):
    def authenticate(self, request):
        print 'authenticate!', request.user
        return (AnonymousUser(), None)
```

When I use `CustomAuthentication`, I get a "maximum recursion depth exceeded" error, and this gets printed in my log:

```
authenticate! authenticate! authenticate! authenticate! authenticate! etc.
```

Removing `request.user` from my print statement fixes this infinite loop. Am I not supposed to use `request.user` when defining a custom auth scheme?

Comment: You should use `request.META.get('field')` to retrieve fields from the header in the request.

Comment: @cziemba thanks. When I do `user = request.META.get('user')`, `user` is `None`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this [document](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/) suggests:

> request.user typically returns an instance of
>   django.contrib.auth.models.User, although the behavior depends on the
>   authentication policy being used.
>
> If the request is unauthenticated the default value of request.user is
>   an instance of django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser.

I think when the request.user is being used, it checks whether the request has user object or not and recursively keeps calling your custom authentication method. You need to return User object in your function.

Comment: `AnonymousUser` is a descendant of `User`, I don't think that's the problem. Returning `AnonymousUser` has worked for me in the past, e.g.: https://github.com/ccnmtl/dmt/blob/master/dmt/api/auth.py#L8

Comment: Right, but the line request.user comes before the AnonymousUser object is set and so it keeps calling the function recursively and does not reach to the return statement.

Comment: thanks for clarifying. That makes sense. I think I figured out what I wanted to do by looking at DRF's `SessionAuthentication`: https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/authentication.py#L113  I need to look at `request._request`.